# about pandas dataframe reverse column's data order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

##### Code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"K1":[1,2,3],"K2":[4,5,6]})
df["result"] = (df["K1"].shift(1)*df["K2"]).fillna(1)[::-1] #line A
print(df["result"])
print((df["K1"].shift(1)*df["K2"]).fillna(1)[::-1]) #line B
print((df["K1"].shift(1)*df["K2"]).fillna(1)) # line C
```

##### Output

```
0     1.0
1     5.0
2    12.0
Name: result, dtype: float64

2    12.0
1     5.0
0     1.0
dtype: float64

0     1.0
1     5.0
2    12.0
dtype: float64
```

Why column result not get reverse order in line A but it work in line B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `[::-1]`, you are reversing the Series, including the index (as you can see by your prints). So, the index-value pairs remain the same. Pandas will use the Series index to align the it to the existing index in the `df` DataFrame. To solve this, you need to assign the raw values to the column, not a Pandas Series, e.g. by using `.to_numpy()`.

```
df["result"] = (df["K1"].shift(1)*df["K2"]).fillna(1).to_numpy()[::-1] #line A
```